# Sulu media display in list

Tags: symfony, sulu

I created an Entity, PlayerInfo. Inside of that, I have photo field and defined MediaInterface, and use it with that. In adminUI everything is shown OK, in Frontend too, but when I got an idea to show thumbnail in list, I get empty field, and error in console that says:

> Invalid type given: "number". "object" is needed. (TRANSFORMER ERROR)

Here is my list XML property code:

```xml
<property name="avatar" visibility="always" translation="sulu_admin.avatar" sortable="false">
    <field-name>id</field-name>
    <entity-name>SuluMediaBundle:Media</entity-name>
    <joins>
        <join>
            <entity-name>SuluMediaBundle:Media</entity-name>
            <field-name>App\Entity\PlayerInfo.photo</field-name>
        </join>
    </joins>

    <transformer type="thumbnails"/>
</property>
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

The `table` adapter of the Sulu list view uses a `transformer` to determine what should be rendered inside of the cell based on the data returned by your API.

You have used the `thumbnails` transformer in your code. If you look at the [`ThumbnailFieldTransformer` implementation](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/5e4f11ac8d160c4a1242b8454265925c72a9cf30/src/Sulu/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/js/containers/List/fieldTransformers/ThumbnailFieldTransformer.js), you see that the transformer expects data in a format like this:

```json
{
    "sulu-40x40":"/uploads/media/sulu-40x40/02/2-isle.jpg?v=1-0",
}
```

I suspect that you have used the `ListBuilder` component of Sulu to gather that list data in the controller that implements your API (like the [sulu-demo project](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-demo/blob/34c059402edafab318ba15efe41c028060b8887c/src/Controller/Admin/AlbumController.php#L44-L51)). The `ListBuilder` component uses optimized queries to load the requested data directly from the database.

Unfortunately, the `ListBuilder` component returns only the ID of the associated media entity and does not transform the data into the format that is expected by the `ThumbnailFieldTransformer` automatically. You need to construct and set the object that contains the thumbnail urls in your controller using the [`MediaManagerInterface::getFormatUrls` method](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/5e4f11ac8d160c4a1242b8454265925c72a9cf30/src/Sulu/Bundle/MediaBundle/Media/Manager/MediaManagerInterface.php#L112-L120).

As an example, you can have a look at how the [organization logo is handled in the `AccountController`](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/5e4f11ac8d160c4a1242b8454265925c72a9cf30/src/Sulu/Bundle/ContactBundle/Controller/AccountController.php#L1250-L1270) that implements the API for the built-in organization list of Sulu:

```php
$ids = \array_filter(\array_column($accounts, 'logo'));
$logos = $this->mediaManager->getFormatUrls($ids, $locale);
foreach ($accounts as $key => $account) {
    if (\array_key_exists('logo', $account) && $account['logo'] && \array_key_exists($account['logo'], $logos)) {
        $accounts[$key]['logo'] = $logos[$account['logo']];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Image in your Entity.

Let's take a "User" Entity for example.
I think you have some kind of property like "avatar".

```
/**
* @var MediaInterface|null
*/
protected $avatar;
```

The error occurs because you have only saved the ID.
The solution is to set the avatar in the Entity before.
e.g. in the controller you call for the list.

```
 $media = $this->container->get('sulu.repository.media')->findMediaById($user->getAvatar()->getId());
 $user->setAvatar($media);
```